# How to store results of select that returns multiple values in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure in T-SQL that collects data and sends email. I'm facing a problem sending multiple results. Below you can see part of the stored procedure:

```
select o.Product 
from vw_order o 
where o.order_id = '7002'
```

Output:

```
tea
coffee
water
```

When I try to send this result to the email stored procedure, I can only send the last value

```
declare @content nvarchar(max)
declare @tid int

select @tid = '7002'

select @content = o.Product  
from vw_order o 
where @tid = o.order_id

exec sp_food_mailer @content
```

Output:

```
water
```

How can I send these all results to the email stored procedure? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need a loop (`while`) if you want to send three emails.

Comment: i dont want to send three or more email. I want to send these results in one email

Comment: You could try `STRING_AGG` to get a single result with all concatenated.

Comment: are you using `sp_send_dbmail` ? You can use the `@query` and `@attach_query_result_as_file` parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `sp_` is a **reserved** prefix by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocedures; it should not use used for User Procedures. Doing so could result in your procedure simply not working one day, and also comes with a performance hit. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: FYI, the behaviour you are getting is both expected and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable): *"If a SELECT statement returns more than one row and the variable references a non-scalar expression, the variable is set to the value returned for the expression in the last row of the result set."*

Comment: Pass a table variable?

Comment: Before any solution could be suggested, we need to know what the **sp_food_mailer** does and what it expects as its parameter. Please edit your question and add the **sp_food_mailer** source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it with :

```
declare @content nvarchar(max)
declare @tid int

select @tid = '7002'

select @content = @content  + o.Product + CHAR(13) +CHAR(10) 
from vw_order o 
where @tid = o.order_id

exec sp_food_mailer @content
```

Answer (score 0):

You need make a cursor

```
DECLARE 
    @product_name VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR
FOR select o.Product 
from vw_order o 
where o.order_id = '7002'

OPEN cursor_product;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO 
    @product_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        exec sp_food_mailer @content
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO 
            @product_name 
    END;

CLOSE cursor_product;

DEALLOCATE cursor_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a temporar table in your main procedure (where you get the list of @content) and call it on your mailing procedure.

Example:

In your main proc:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempContentTbl(
   content nvarchar(max),
)

INSERT INTO #TempContentTbl(
   content
)
select o.Product 
from vw_order o 
where o.order_id = '7002'

exec sp_food_mailer
```

In your email procedure, you can just select the tempTable to retrieve all the data. You don't need to create the temporary table in your email procedure since it was created in the main procedure.

There is also no need of passing @content as a variable to your procedure as you will be using the temporary table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, i solved my question with using attachment. Have a good day